# Is there is 'dict.setdefault' equivalent for sets?

Tags: python, dictionary

A common pattern when working with a set is the following:

```
number_list = [1,5,7,2,4,4,1,3,8,5]
number_set = set()

for number in number_list:

   #we only want to process the number if we haven't already processed it
   if(number not in number_set):
       number_set.add(number)

       #do processing of 'number' here now that we know it's not a duplicate
```

The lines `if(number not in number_set):` and `number_set.add(number)` bug me because we're doing two hash lookups here, when realistically we should only need one.

Dictionaries have the "setdefault" operation, which solves a very similar problem: "If the key exists in the dictionary, return the value, otherwise insert this default and then return the default". If you do this naively, IE the following, you perform two hash lookups, but setdefault allows you to do it in one

```
if item_key in dict:
   dict[item_key].append(item_value)
else:
   dict[item_key] = [item_value]
```

Is there an equivalent operation for sets? Something like `if(number_set.check_if_contains_and_then_add(number)):` but given a much nicer name.

Comment: Why can't you just do `number_set  = set(number_list)`?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil in the example I gave that would be the correct choice, but it doesn't work if you don't know the full contents of the list before you begin, or if you have an iderator you don't want to consume all at once

Comment: Since something cannot be in a set more than once, just unconditional add it, if it's already there, nothing will change and no harm done.

Comment: It would be nice if set.add returned a boolean indicating whether there was in fact anything newly added, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the profiler tells you that hash lookups contribute significant runtime, then this might work around it.

```
def add_value(container, value):
    oldlen = len(container)
    container.add(value)
    return len(container) != oldlen

if add_value(number_set, number):
    # process number
```

But why would that be? Perhaps due to a slow `__hash__` method, although I can tell you now that (a) hashing integers isn't slow and (b) if you possibly can, it's better to make the class with the slow `__hash__` cache the result instead of reducing the number of calls. Or perhaps due to a slow `__eq__`, which is harder to deal with. Finally if the internal lookup mechanism itself is slow, then there may not be a great deal you can do to speed your program up, because the runtime is doing hash lookups all the time, finding names in scopes.

It would probably be nice for `set.add` to return a value indicating whether or not the set changed, but I think that idea runs up against a principle of the Python libraries (admittedly not universally upheld) that mutating operations don't return a value unless it's fundamental to the operation to do so. So `pop()` functions return a value of course, but `list.sort()` returns `None` even though it would occasionally be useful to users if it returned `self`.

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
def deduped(iterable):
    seen = set()
    count = 0
    for value in iterable:
        seen.add(value)
        if count != len(seen):
            count += 1
            yield value

for number in deduped(number_list):
    # process number
```

Of course it's pure speculation that the repeated hash lookup is any kind of problem: I would normally write either of those functions with the `if not in` test as in your original code, and the purpose of the function would be to simplify the calling code, not to avoid superfluous hash lookups.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not.

The `setdefault` method is used to set the default **value** of a key in dictionaries, sets don't have values so that is completely pointless.

Try this instead if the order doesn't matter.

```
number_list = [1,5,7,2,4,4,1,3,8,5]
number_set = set(number_list)

for number in number_set:
   #do processing of 'number' here now that we know it's not a duplicate
```

Comment: Good answer, but you meant to lose the pointless call to the `add()` method.

Comment: @Duncan yes, I didn't notice it at first. Thanks for the alert.

Comment: This answer works when the entire list is known beforehand, but falls short if you're using an iterator that you don't want to consume all at once, or for something like a breadth first search where the whole list isn't known at the start of the algorithm

Comment: @Elliott regardless of the shortcomings of the snippet, the answer is still "no", there is no `setdefault` equivalent for sets. Also, `e in set` and `set.add(e)` are not actually the same operation.

Comment: @OdraEncoded Maybe I should have been more clear, but the point is that we're pointlessly doing multiple hash lookups, one for the "in" operation and another for the "add" operation, not that "in" and "add" do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do `number_set.add(number)`? The point of setdefault is that it won't overwrite the existing value for a key, if it exists. But a set doesn't have a value, just a key, so overwriting is irrelevant.

Comment: "Why wouldn't you just do `number_set.add(number)`?" -- because without the `if not in` test, any duplicates in `number_list` would be processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no `setdefault` type method for `sets`, but you can do something like this:

```
number_list = [1,5,7,2,4,4,1,3,8,5]
number_set = set()

for number in number_list:
   if number not in number_set and not number_set.add(number):
       #do somethihng here
```

The `not number_set.add(number)` condition will be called only if `number not in number_set` is `True`.

Using this you can process the unique items in ordered way(preserving the order).

```
>>> number_list = [1,5,7,2,4,4,1,3,8,5]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in number_list if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
[1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 8]
```

If the order doesn't matter then simply call `set()` on `number_list`:

```
>>> set(number_list)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

Comment: I like that this does both operations in one line, but i feel like `and not number_set.add(number)` will be unreadable - it's true that "void" methods actually return None, but it's hard to distinguish that from relying on an actual boolean return value

Comment: I'd write `number_set.add(number) is None` instead of `not number_set.add(number)`.  It seems clearer to me.

Comment: There is absolutely no point putting that function inside the if clause condition.